# Why call general template function?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

     template <typename T> void compare(const T&, const T&){
        cout<<"T"<<endl;
     }
     void compare(const char*, const char*){

        cout<<"const char*"<<endl;
     }

int main()
{

     char a[]="123";

     char b[]="123";

     char *p1 = a, *p2 = b;

     compare(p1,p2);
    return 0;
}
```

the result is: T

but why? after instantiation the template function may be so:

compare(const char*&, const char*&)

is the same as ordinary function. and the ordinary function should be called!

Comment: but why compare(const char*&, const char*&) is the exact match??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why I think writing `T const&` is superior to writing `const T&`.

The template function is instantiated with the signature `void(char* const&, char* const&)` which is a better match than `void(char const*, char const*)`, as it requires no conversions of the pointers from `char*` to `char const*`.

Comment: *"writing `T const&` is superior to writing `const T&`."*. But in this case, it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @Nawaz It does make a difference. It led the OP to the wrong conclusion: `char* const&` is not the same as `const char*&` (http://ideone.com/ilycp).

Comment: @Nawaz: It reduces confusion if you erroneously think that the template argument would be simply pasted into the expression, giving `const char*&`.

Comment: why  void(char* const&, char* const&)  requires no conversions of the pointers from char* to char const*  ?

Comment: @huwang Erm, because the function doesn't take `char const*`?

Comment: @huwang: Because there's no conversion to `char const*` involved. `char * const &` is a reference to a `char *`, not to `char const*`.

Comment: @Nawaz: It reduces confusion if you erroneously think that the template argument would be simply pasted into the expression, giving const char*&   ---- and what's the rule?

Comment: @huwang: You don't really know "how to comment", do you? Please learn to comment as well.

Comment: @Mike Seymour:It reduces confusion if you erroneously think that the template argument would be simply pasted into the expression, giving const char*& ---- and what's the rule?

Comment: @huwang: The `const` is applied to the type `T`, whether you write `const T&` or `T const&`. In this case, `T` is instantiated as `char*`, so the `const` applies to the pointer, not its target. That means the function parameter types are `char* const&`, not `char const *&`. If you follow the guideline of always putting `const` *after* the type it refers to, then this confusion won't arise.

Answer (score 1):

`T` is deduced as `char *`, which gives an exact match. For the other overload, you'd have to say,

```
 compare(static_cast<char const *>(p1), static_cast<char const *>(p2));
```

to make it a better match.

(Or just declare `p1` and `p2` as `char const *` in the first place.)

Comment: and  compare(const char*&, const char*&)  don't need converting?

Comment: @huwang your assumption is wrong. It's not `compare(const char*&, const char*&)`.

Comment: @huwang: The `char*` argument instantiates the template with `T=char*`, taking `char* const&` arguments. Even though you put the `const` before `T` rather than after it, it still applies to the template argument type (`char*`), not to the pointer target type (`char`).

Comment: @huwang: An lvalue of type `U` binds to a `U&` on the nose.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning `a`, and `b` to const's will not make them const's, that may be the source of confusion. How you declare them is the more important part. I believe you'd need to declare them as Kerrek SB said, to get what you're after...